# Facebook App request not sending to Facebook friends through Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send app request to one friend as well as to all friend at a time.I had followed the following posts,

[how-to-send-app-requests-to-friends-through-facebook-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153175/how-to-send-app-requests-to-friends-through-facebook-android-sdk)

[dialogs/requests/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

I am able to get the correct response as described in the Dev site but the problem is none of my friends are getting the app request notification.Following is what I have tried,

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("FIRST INVITATION", "My invitation from facebook..");
    params.putString("message", "My First App Invitation from Android App to facebook.Lol");
    params.putString("app_id",APP_ID);
    mFacebook.dialog(this, "apprequests", params, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
        }
    });
```

can anyone tell me what went wrong here??

**EDIT:1**

I checked the Hackbook sample Application  APP ID which comes with Facebook SDK,and my app works fine So came to know that there must be some problem in app setting.I disabled the sandbox mode too.Is there any extra setting required in order to send app request??

**EDIT-2**

After some R & D I came to know the real problem.There is no problem in the coding part.I was making mistake in app setting in the FB Dashboard. I need to add a Facebook Hash key in the app setting.Anyways, thanks all for your help.

Comment: See my answer for both app request and friend request

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153175/how-to-send-app-requests-to-friends-through-facebook-android-sdk/14976274#14976274

Comment: Please see this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/games/requests/

Comment: @Kirit: Thanks for your reply. I tried as you said but  Session.getActiveSession() shows null and the app charshes.

Comment: You can try this tutorial http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some R&D, I came to know that the coding part is all ok.The problem lies in the Facebook app setting.I did the following to solve the issue,

**1.Set the required fields in the Native Android App section.**

**i. Package Name**: Package name of your android project.Setting this field helps navigating to GooglePlay page of your application.

**ii.Class Name**: The launcher class of your project. Setting this helps to open the specified page of your app if installed.

**iii.Key Hashes**: It is used for a security check for authorizing your app.

**iv.Facebook Login**: should be enabled.

**v.Deep Linking**: Should be enabled.

**2.Set the Android Key Hash in the developer setting.**

Answer (score 1):

**Direct the request**

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "I just smashed " + application.getScore() +
    " friends! Can you beat it?");
// 2. Optionally provide a 'to' param to direct the request at a specific user
params.putString("to", "515768651");  // Phil
showDialogWithoutNotificationBar("apprequests", params);
```

**Suggest friends**

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "I just smashed " + application.getScore() +
    " friends! Can you beat it?");
String [] suggestedFriends = {
    "695755709",
    "685145706",
    "569496010",
    "286400088",
    "627802916",
};
params.putString("suggestions", TextUtils.join(",", suggestedFriends));
showDialogWithoutNotificationBar("apprequests", params);
```

Ref : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/games/requests/

Comment: Well, I have already tried the exact like your answer and I am also getting the correct response as Dev site says but strangely none of my friends are getting any notification regarding this.Is it working for you now?

Comment: if you send any request or app request from Facebook android sdk than it only visible in Facebook android application

Comment: yeah dude I checked the corresponding Facebook profile in desktop browser but they didn't received any notification.Is it only meant for android Facebook?

Comment: Install facebook android app in device than check the notification