# Facebook android sdk - send requests not working?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to use the send-requests feature of the android sdk:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/

I've copy and pasted their sample from the link above. It pops up a friend picker dialog, but it does not have a preview message like in their screenshot, even though the 'message' attribute is set:

```
params.putString("message", "hi hi hi");
```

I put a log statement in the facebook code to see what url the webview is loading, I do see the param in there:

```
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests
    ?access_token=xxx
    &type=user_agent
    &redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
    &message=hi%20hi%20hi
    &display=touch
```

but no message preview. More problematic is that after I send the message off to a few of my friends, they never receive the message.

Anyone else run into this?

This question provided some ideas, but I've already set the android app settings in the facebook developer settings:

[Facebook App request not sending to Facebook friends through Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107933/facebook-app-request-not-sending-to-facebook-friends-through-facebook-android-sd)

My only guesses at this point:

1. I haven't submitted the facebook app to the facebook app center for review yet.
2. The android app is not published on google play yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, this was because my facebook project was not in a published state (I'm developing it now), and the user I was trying to send the messages to was not marked as a developer or tester of my project.

What an epic waste of time - would be nice if the facebook api could return a simple error message giving you a hint.