# How to send app invitation to selected friends using Facebook SDK 4.0+ in android

Tags: android, android-facebook

Currently I am developing an Android app for that I am using the Facebook SDK 4.0. My question is, How can I send app invitations to selected users in facebook using Facebook sdk 4.0.

I have found solution on  link ([How to send app requests to friends through Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153175/how-to-send-app-requests-to-friends-through-facebook-android-sdk)), but that works on below sdk 4.0 version.

Thanks